# Is phase defined for species undergoing diffusion?

Tags: diffusion

1. If we have a gas diffusing through say a solid metal, or gas diffusing into a liquid, what phase is the diffusing molecules considered to be in (or is it even possible to define this)? Is it possible to define state properties for molecules diffusing through another substance.
2. Is it possible for liquid (or even solids) to diffuse through solids, like for water in a metal container? If so how would one define the density gradient? In my mass transfer book every problem deals with gas diffusion through a liquid/solid species so I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: 1) The phase of a substance is a macroscopic property and hence is not defined for individual atoms/molecules. 2) Yes, both solids and liquids can diffuse through solids, though the corresponding diffusion coefficients are extremely small typically, and for solid-solid diffusion, the diffusion mechanisms may also be anomalous.

Comment: @surajshankar so it wouldn't make sense/not possible to define a temperature/pressure (or any thermodynamic state property) for something like dissolved air or molecules diffusing through a solid? What if we have single phase diffusion (gas through gas or liquid through liquid)?

Comment: It depends on what you are talking about. If, say, you are talking of diffusion at the continuum level, then there are well defined macroscopic properties associated with it as the material, though diffusing, still has a large amount of constituent atoms or molecules and hence their phase is in principle the same as that of the pure material (though the idea of phase is not very useful while thinking of diffusion, but temperature/pressure can be defined).

Comment: Only when you are talking of low density diffusion (like Knudsen diffusion) or probing the system at microscopic length scales, then the continuum diffusion description fails and one must resort to a more appropriate detailed theory (say, kinetic models) and then what I said before about macroscopic properties being undefined, applies.

Comment: How does one differentiate whether it is low density scale diffusion or a continuum? Intuitively I am thinking that gas dissolving in liquid or through solids is low density, but something like the Stefan problem isn't?

Comment: One typically has separation of scales in a problem which helps identify whether the problem description is to be discrete or continuum. It can also be a matter of some phenomena which a particular description might not capture. When you have say a gas diffusing into a liquid, the "diffusion interface" of sorts (at and beyond which say the gas present is negligible), does not in it self have a well defined phase, though one could associate a phase to it, inherited from the bulk (that is the liquid in this case).

Comment: Even in the above case, the most sensible description of phase is actually just decided by the bulk and the fact that liquid has some diffused gas in it does not change its phase.